# How can I transform the json output from Google Analytics into a Pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics-api

TLDR: How can I transform the json output from Google Analytics into a Pandas dataframe in Python?

I'm using the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) to get results out of Google Analytics. This works, but I would like to have the output in a pandas dataframe for further data analysis instead of in json format.

Remarks:

- When you look at the code below, you'll see that I've commented out '''print(response)''' because that outputs the results in json format.
- I've used the code from [this article](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/getting-started-with-the-google-analytics-reporting-api-in-python/) to write the pandas part.
- I've searched extensively on Stackoverflow to find a solution but to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

```
def get_report(analytics):
    """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:adMatchedQuery'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()

response = get_report(initialize_analyticsreporting())
'''print(response)'''

def print_response(response):
    list = []
    # get report data
    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        # set column headers
        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
        rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    
    for row in rows:
        # create dict for each row
        dict = {}
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

        # fill dict with dimension header (key) and dimension value (value)
        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
          dict[header] = dimension

        # fill dict with metric header (key) and metric value (value)
        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
            #set int as int, float a float
                if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                else:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)

        list.append(dict)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    return df
```

Comment: What have you tried, can you describe any issues you are having?

Comment: Hi DalmTo. Thanks for your reply. See below for an example of my output. I want this output in a dataframe.  So I need to do something to read over the output and print that in/as a dataframe. I just don't know how and I've tried lots of articles. 

```ga:adMatchedQuery:  (not set)
Date range: 0
ga:sessions: 842
ga:adMatchedQuery:  blablah1
Date range: 0
ga:sessions: 1
ga:adMatchedQuery:  blablah2
Date range: 0
ga:sessions: 1
ga:adMatchedQuery:  blablah3
Date range: 0
ga:sessions: 1
ga:adMatchedQuery:  blablah4
Date range: 0
ga:sessions: 2
ga:adMatchedQuery:  blablah5```

Comment: @user15402899 did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @mrmatt11, unfortunately not.